# Servlet-MongoDb Project :Db connection

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets

I develop basic user management project using Servlet-JSP-MongoDB.My codes are bellow.After I run project on Tomcat ,I take exception on console as follows.

Why is this problem,please help me?

package com.fatih.controller;

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.fatih.dao.UserDAO;
    import com.fatih.model.User;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class AddUser
     */
    @WebServlet("/addUser")
    public class AddUser extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public AddUser() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String email=request.getParameter("emailId");
            String password=request.getParameter("password");

            if( (name==null || name.equals(""))||
                (email==null || email.equals(""))||
                (password==null || password.equals(""))){

                request.setAttribute("error", "All fields are required!");
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/users.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

            }else{

                User user=new User();

                user.setName(name);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setPassword(password);

                MongoClient mongoClient=(MongoClient) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("MONGO_CLIENT");

                UserDAO userDAO=new UserDAO(mongoClient);

                userDAO.createUser(user);




                request.setAttribute("success", "User added");
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/users.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);


            }

            System.out.println("name: "+name+"\nemail: "+email+"\npassword: "+password);

        }

    }
```

.......................................................................

```
 package com.fatih.conventer;

    import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

    import com.fatih.model.User;
    import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
    import com.mongodb.DBObject;

    public class UserConventer {

        public static DBObject toDBObject(User user) {

            BasicDBObjectBuilder builder=BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                    .append("name", user.getName())
                    .append("email", user.getEmail())
                    .append("password", user.getPassword());

            if(user.getId()!=null){
                builder=builder.append("_id", new ObjectId(user.getId()));
            }



            return builder.get();
        }
}
```

..........................................................................

```
    package com.fatih.dao;

    import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

    import com.fatih.conventer.UserConventer;
    import com.fatih.model.User;
    import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
    import com.mongodb.DBObject;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

    public class UserDAO {

        private DBCollection dbCollection;

        public UserDAO(MongoClient mongoClient) {
            this.dbCollection=mongoClient.getDB("usersDB").getCollection("users");
        }


        public User createUser(User user){

            DBObject dbObject=UserConventer.toDBObject(user);
            this.dbCollection.insert(dbObject);
            ObjectId id=(ObjectId) dbObject.get("_id");
            user.setId(id.toString());
            return user;
        }


}
```

..........................................................

```
 package com.fatih.listener;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
    import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

    @WebListener
    public class MongoDBListener implements ServletContextListener{

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            MongoClient mongoClient=(MongoClient) sce.getServletContext().getAttribute("MONGO_CLIENT");
            mongoClient.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

            ServletContext context=sce.getServletContext();
            MongoClient mongoClient=new MongoClient(context.getInitParameter("MONGO_HOST"),Integer.parseInt(context.getInitParameter("MONGO_PORT")));
            sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("MONGO_CLIENT", mongoClient);



        }

    }
```

......................................................................

```
package com.fatih.model;

    public class User {

        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private String password;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }



    }

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>KullaniciYonetimSistemiMongoDB</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>MONGO_HOST</param-name>
    <param-value>localhost</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>MONGO_PORT</param-name>
    <param-value>27017</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>users.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>

Consol output is bellow:
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:KullaniciYonetimSistemiMongoDB' did not find a matching property.
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.36.0
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\wtpwebapps
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\endorsed
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1254
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\;C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\adb; C:\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm;%M2%;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;;C:\Users\mypc\Downloads\programlar\eclipse;;.
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2248 ms
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:26 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:26 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\docs
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\docs has finished in 35 ms
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\examples
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\examples has finished in 586 ms
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\host-manager
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\host-manager has finished in 64 ms
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\manager
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\manager has finished in 58 ms
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\ROOT
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\javaTools\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\webapps\ROOT has finished in 33 ms
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2953 ms
Kas 26, 2016 4:53:28 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
    **INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
    com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket**
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more

**Kas 26, 2016 4:53:37 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
 INFO: No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out**
**Kas 26, 2016 4:54:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.fatih.controller.AddUser] in context with path [/KullaniciYonetimSistemiMongoDB] threw exception
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]**
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:375)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:827)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:810)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:333)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:319)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:192)
    at com.fatih.dao.UserDAO.createUser(UserDAO.java:23)
    at com.fatih.controller.AddUser.doPost(AddUser.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

***IN WEB BROWSER:***

**HTTP Status 500 - Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]**

**type Exception report
message Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
    com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:375)
    com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:104)
    com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:68)
    com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:134)
    com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:61)
    com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:827)
    com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:810)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:333)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:319)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:289)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:255)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:192)
    com.fatih.dao.UserDAO.createUser(UserDAO.java:23)
    com.fatih.controller.AddUser.doPost(AddUser.java:69)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 logs.**
```

Comment: looks like either hostname/port is incorrect or your mongo server is not running

Comment: I wrote  host and port in web xml as context parameter localhost and 27017

Comment: Is your server running ?

Comment: yes I runned server with mongod command

Comment: that's all I can pick from logs you posted

Comment: How do you connecting to remote MongoDB cloud database like mLab with Servlets?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem;I change mongodb java driver version from 3.0.1 to 2.13.3 in pom.xml.Project run succesfully.